# Parallel Merge Sort Performance

Tags: parallel-processing, mergesort

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of how much I could speed up merge sort if I parallelize it.

My thoughts so far:

If N is the number of elements in the array to be sorted, then log(base 2)N is the highest number of cores I'd need. I believe this is the case because there are 2*log(base 2)N + 1 levels in mergesort. First, you break it up by dividing it by two over and over, then you merge two sorted arrays over and over until you have an array of N items again (and now it is sorted).

I'm trying to figure out how much this would actually improve performance. I'm thinking that the increase in performance due to additional cores will increase as we move towards the middle of the algorithm, because we can use more cores. Say I have 16 items in an unsorted array. I only need to use one core to break it up into two 8 item arrays, and then I can use two cores to break those into four 4 item arrays, etc.

So, the performance will increase by a factor of two for every level of splitting, and then decrease by two for every level of merging... right? Am I on the right track here?

Also, why couldn't we just start by merging the first two items in the unsorted array, then the next two and so on. Basically get rid of the first half of the algorithm?

Thoughts?

Should I ask this at math.stackexchange.com instead? Sorry if so... I didn't really know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase performance of MergeSort via parallelization, you should parallelize the splitting (the part you do before you merge the results). I assume you have multiple CPU nodes.

**Splitting:**
Have the current CPU node keep one half of the array and give to another CPU node the other half. Keep repeating this process. Parallelism will increase as you go deeper into the tree (as you mentioned)

**Base case:**
When the data is one item the current CPU node sends it back to its parent node.
The parent nodes will wait for the children nodes to pass up data before doing any merging back.

**Merging:**
Once data from a node's child is received, the node (parent of that child) can start merging the received data with its own data. After merging is done, it passes it up to its parent node and so on. Since each node is an individual CPU, merging at lower levels is done in parallel. This parallelism decreases as we go up the tree. (just like you mentioned)

This should speed up merge sort.

However, this article on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Parallel_processing shows that you can speed up the merge step to O(1) by parallelizing and specializing it (as well as throwing in insertion sort when data size <11)

I am curious why you don't use Quicksort. It lends itself to parallelization nicely!

Edit:

> Also, why couldn't we just start by merging the first two items in the
>   unsorted array, then the next two and so on. Basically get rid of the
>   first half of the algorithm?

**And to answer your question:**

That is what merge sort is doing, it is merging the first 2, next 2 and so on, but in order to get to them it uses recursion. Which makes the runtime O(n*2log(n)) because there are 2 trees (one created when splitting and one created when merging back into one big list). This comes out to O(nlog(n)).

Take your idea, start at the bottom and take 2 by 2 numbers and sort them. Then enlarge the boundaries to encompass 2 chunks (each w 2 numbers) 4 numbers... and so on. You are building a tree, from leaves to root. This is similar to the tournament algorithm (though there you can have only one winner-the root of the tree).

Runtime: at first you have have n numbers. You loop so set the boundaries on every 2 numbers O(n/2), next level O(n/4), next O(n/8) and so on.
To build this tree is takes O(log(n)). But you still have to merge the other numbers into a list. Since you have n numbers, that is n*O(nlogn) giving you the same runtime as merge sort nlogn.

**Summary:**
So what I am trying to say is that your idea of merging from the bottom is still nlong. You are getting rid of one of the trees so the speed up is not significant.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

Dual Pivot QuickSort is known to have beaten Merge Sort in serial versions. I think the parallel form of DPQ could really be the best fastest sorting algorithm ever created. Reason is that it has low constant factors than MergeSort and its worst case time complexity has the probability of occuring only 1/(n!). If N is large, prefer DPQ, maybe multithread it, if its possible. But parallelism has a pivot or limit, below the limit its slow due to Thread Management. Beyond the limit it is much faster. In case you are interested, serial code is below( both ascending and descending)

```
protected static void ASC(int[]a, int left, int right, int div)
{
    int len = 1 + right - left;
    if (len < 27)
    {
        // insertion sort for small array
        int P1 = left + 1;
        int P2 = left;
        while ( P1 <= right )
        {
            div = a[P1];
            while(( P2 >= left )&&( a[P2] > div ))
            {
                a[P2 + 1] = a[P2];
                P2--;
            }
            a[P2 + 1] = div;
            P2 = P1;
            P1++;
        }
        return;
    }
    int third = len / div;
    // "medians"
    int P1 = left + third;
    int P2 = right - third;
    if (P1 <= left)
    {
        P1 = left + 1;
    }
    if (P2 >= right)
    {
        P2 = right - 1;
    }
    int temp;
    if (a[P1] < a[P2])
    {
        temp = a[P1]; a[P1] = a[left]; a[left] = temp;
        temp = a[P2]; a[P2] = a[right]; a[right] = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = a[P1];  a[P1] = a[right];  a[right] = temp;
        temp = a[P2];  a[P2] = a[left];  a[left] = temp;
    }
    // pivots
    int pivot1 = a[left];
    int pivot2 = a[right];
    // pointers
    int less = left + 1;
    int great = right - 1;
    // sorting
    for (int k = less; k <= great; k++)
    {
        if (a[k] < pivot1)
        {
            temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
            less++;
        }
        else if (a[k] > pivot2)
        {
            while (k < great && a[great] > pivot2)
            {
                great--;
            }
            temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[great];  a[great] = temp;
            great--;
            if (a[k] < pivot1)
            {
                temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
                less++;
            }
        }
    }
    int dist = great - less;
    if (dist < 13)
    {
        div++;
    }
    temp = a[less-1];  a[less-1] = a[left];  a[left] = temp;
    temp = a[great+1];  a[great+1] = a[right];  a[right] = temp;
    // subarrays
    ASC(a, left, less - 2, div);
    ASC(a, great + 2, right, div);
    // equal elements
    if (dist > len - 13 && pivot1 != pivot2)
    {
        for (int k = less; k <= great; k++)
        {
            if (a[k] == pivot1)
            {
                temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
                less++;
            }
            else if (a[k] == pivot2)
            {
                temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[great];  a[great] = temp;
                great--;
                if (a[k] == pivot1)
                {
                    temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
                    less++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // subarray
    if (pivot1 < pivot2)
    {
        ASC(a, less, great, div);
    }
}

protected static void DSC(int[]a, int left, int right, int div)
{
    int len = 1 + right - left;
    if (len < 27)
    {
        // insertion sort for large array
        int P1 = left + 1;
        int P2 = left;
        while ( P1 <= right )
        {
            div = a[P1];
            while(( P2 >= left )&&( a[P2] < div ))
            {
                a[P2 + 1] = a[P2];
                P2--;
            }
            a[P2 + 1] = div;
            P2 = P1;
            P1++;
        }
        return;
    }
    int third = len / div;
    // "medians"
    int P1 = left + third;
    int P2 = right - third;
    if (P1 >= left)
    {
        P1 = left + 1;
    }
    if (P2 <= right)
    {
        P2 = right - 1;
    }
    int temp;
    if (a[P1] > a[P2])
    {
        temp = a[P1]; a[P1] = a[left]; a[left] = temp;
        temp = a[P2]; a[P2] = a[right]; a[right] = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = a[P1];  a[P1] = a[right];  a[right] = temp;
        temp = a[P2];  a[P2] = a[left];  a[left] = temp;
    }
    // pivots
    int pivot1 = a[left];
    int pivot2 = a[right];
    // pointers
    int less = left + 1;
    int great = right - 1;
    // sorting
    for (int k = less; k <= great; k++)
    {
        if (a[k] > pivot1)
        {
            temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
            less++;
        }
        else if (a[k] < pivot2)
        {
            while (k < great && a[great] < pivot2)
            {
                great--;
            }
            temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[great];  a[great] = temp;
            great--;
            if (a[k] > pivot1)
            {
                temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
                less++;
            }
        }
    }
    int dist = great - less;
    if (dist < 13)
    {
        div++;
    }
    temp = a[less-1];  a[less-1] = a[left];  a[left] = temp;
    temp = a[great+1];  a[great+1] = a[right];  a[right] = temp;
    // subarrays
    DSC(a, left, less - 2, div);
    DSC(a, great + 2, right, div);
    // equal elements
    if (dist > len - 13 && pivot1 != pivot2)
    {
        for (int k = less; k <= great; k++)
        {
            if (a[k] == pivot1)
            {
                temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
                less++;
            }
            else if (a[k] == pivot2)
            {
                temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[great];  a[great] = temp;
                great--;
                if (a[k] == pivot1)
                {
                    temp = a[k];  a[k] = a[less];  a[less] = temp;
                    less++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // subarray
    if (pivot1 > pivot2)
    {
        DSC(a, less, great, div);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In parallel have each processor sort n/p of the array serially.

2) For i=1 to log_2(p)
You have have to merge two arrays with 2^i processors.
In O( log 2^i) time use one processor do a binary search using the midpoint of the largest section of an array (of which we split into two parts) into the other array to find where it matches and form another partition there.

Example:

A= 12345  6789

B= 1234   567 89

The largest section is 12345, midpoint being the 3. Use binary search to find where this 3 is in the other array and split it. New arrays:

A= 12 345 6789
B= 12 34  567 89

You can use a priority queue to keep track of which array section is largest.

After you have both the A and B arrays split into O(p) sections you can do serial merge in parallel on each of these small chunks. To get the offsets of where the output for each pairing goes you can do a parallel prefix sum before hand.

O(n/p log n/p) //serial sort, only O(n/p) if you can radix sort

O( log(p) *(log(p) +(n/p) ) = O(log(p)^2 + log(p)(n/p)) // parallel merging